# Norm convergence of a net of operators

Tags: convergence-divergence, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $T$ be a positive operator in B(H). For every $\epsilon >0$, define $T_{\epsilon}:=(T+\epsilon I)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. This makes sense since the spectrum of $T$ lies in $[\epsilon,\infty)$. Let $S$ be any other operator in $B(H)$. Then I want to show that if $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, then $$\|T_\epsilon S T_\epsilon -T^{-\frac{1}{2}}ST^{-\frac{1}{2}}\|\rightarrow 0.$$

I am not sure if $T^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is always defined. What should be the starting point? Hints are most welcome.

Comment: I think your question (in this version) does not make sens. Since (as you said) $T^{\frac{-1}{2}}$  does not defined unless $T$ is invertible.

Comment: If we assume that $T$ is invertible then to show your assertion, it is enough to show that $$||T_{\epsilon}-T||\to 0$$ where $\epsilon$ tends to zero. But it is directly obtained by  the functional calculus.